# Replacing a variable in a loop by records from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Date Table like this one:

```
Exit_Date  Date_ID
2017-05-31    1
2017-04-26    2
2017-01-02    3
2016-12-24    4
2016-11-27    5
```

I use a loop to insert each of those Dates into a CTE to generates the last 15 years of these dates like this:

```
declare @DI int = 1
declare @d date
while @DI <=5
begin
    select @d = Exit_Date from Date_Table where Date_ID = @DI
    declare @EDTable table (Exit_Date  Date);
    with
      a as(
        select dateadd(yy,-1,@d) d,0 i
          union all
        select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<14
      ),
      b as(select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a)
     insert into @EDTable select d from b;
      set @DI = @DI + 1
 end
```

The results is correct, I get 75 rows with my dates. I would like to know if there is a way to get rid of the *WHILE* loop by replacing variable `@d` by each date record from *Date_Table*?

Comment: have you considered using a cursor? while it is very similar to a *WHILE* loop, it allows looping over results from a query... Also, is **Date_ID** a unique/primary key column, or could there be multiple records with the same value in that field yet different values in the **Exit_date** field?

Comment: Date_ID is unique/primary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Selecting from Date_Table in a

One option is to select `Exit_Date` direct from `Date_Table` in a. The ordering of the end results won't be the same so you may need to add an `ORDER BY` clause (e.g. with `DATEPART()`).

```
 with
      a as(
        select dateadd(yy,-1,Exit_date) d,0 i
        from Date_Table WHERE Date_ID <=5
          union all
        select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<14
      ),
      b as(select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a)
SELECT d from b --order by DATEPART(MM,d) desc
```

See a sample [here in this SQLFidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdb9d/25).

#### Cursor

Like I mentioned in my comment, another option is to use a Transact-SQL [cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql). In the squery below, we keep the temp variables `@d` and `@EDTable`. The `SELECT` statement from `Date_Table` could have `ORDER BY Date_ID ASC` added if you wanted to ensure those go in order (in case the records were not added sequentially).

```
declare @d date;
declare @EDTable table (Exit_Date  Date);
declare dateCursor CURSOR FOR 
    select Exit_Date from Date_Table WHERE Date_Id <=5;
    
OPEN dateCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM dateCursor INTO @d

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    with
      a as(
        select dateadd(yy,-1,@d) d,0 i
          union all
        select dateadd(yy,-1,d),i+1 from a where i<14
      ),
      b as(select d,datediff(dd,0,d)%7 dd from a)
     insert into @EDTable select d from b;--*/
    FETCH NEXT FROM dateCursor   
    INTO @d 
END   
CLOSE dateCursor;  
DEALLOCATE dateCursor;  

SELECT * FROM @EDTable
```

I am trying to get a SQL Fiddle working but having issues with the line endings. I will update when I figure that out.

Comment: That solution still use a loop though, that is what I try to avoid as I expect the date table to be big

Comment: Even the first option, which doesn't use the cursor?

Comment: yes the first option works without the loop, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another option that will perform better at larger scales than recursion would be a numbers table, or virtual numbers table.

Using `row_number()` and the system view `master..spt_values` for a source of rows:

```
select Exit_Date = dateadd(year, -x.n, d.exit_date)
from date_table d
  cross join (
    select top (15) --<-- number of rows is 15 for 0 to 14
      n = row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1
    from master..spt_values
    order by n
  ) x
where d.date_id <= 5
```

[dbfiddle.uk demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f087259399beafcbf0495a9c44cda4ff)

Reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)